# How to convert a big project to requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

The project is use js like this:

One jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="**********"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="**********"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="**********"/>
```

and each js file is like:

```
$.omatrix.a = {
   amethod : function(){

}
$.omatrix.a.summary = {


}
```

and so on.

Because I will use two js files, they are all fusioncharts, one is charts, and the other is widgets,
and the two file conflict, so I have to use requirejs to resolve the situation.
But when I use, I found the one js file `$.omatrix` is undefined, I don't know why.